# What is it : int l when l>0 && l<5

Tags: c#

Looking for solution form switch command I've bumped on code :
(I don't remember the example exacly)

```cs
    switch (i)
    {
       case **int n when n>0 && n<5**:
         DoSth();
         break;
       case int n when n>=5:
    ....

    }
```

```
So, I understand how it works
but I saw for a first time this declaratio

**int n when n ....**

what is it ?? 
Where can I read about It?
```

Comment: See MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#when

Comment: Search for "Case When C#" in a search engine. -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch. Then Crtl + F "When".-> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#when

Answer (score 2):

[`case when` is a new construct added in C# 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/when#when-in-a-switch-statement). According to the docs:

> Starting with C# 7.0, case labels no longer need be mutually exclusive, and the order in which case labels appear in a switch statement can determine which switch block executes. The when keyword can be used to specify a filter condition that causes its associated case label to be true only if the filter condition is also true.

So in simpler terms, it allows you to add a condition that must be true for a  `case` to be selected - if you had something like this (contrived) example:

```cs
switch (val) {
    case int n when n > 5:
        return true;
    case int n:
        return false;
}
```

It would be the same as:

```cs
switch (val) {
    case int n:
        if (n > 5) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```